# How to reduce running time of prime BigInteger mapreduce code?

Tags: performance, mapreduce, primes, biginteger

I am trying to generate  prime BigIntegers of size 1764 bits(531 digits).when I do this on local computer it takes very long time. So I try mapreduce for generating BigIntegers and run on single node cloudera (CDH 4). But this takes lots of time in maping. Can I reduce the time by applying mapreduce and implementing it on multinode cluster? and my second question is is this program can be improved for better efficiency and How?

My input file consist of 90 entries containing "1764"  which is the number of bits random BigInteger generated. Here is my code for mapreduce

```
public final class Primes {

public final static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {

   final Configuration conf = new Configuration();

   final Job job = new Job(conf, "Primes");
   job.setJarByClass(Primes.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(NullWritable.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    job.setMapperClass(PrimesMap.class);

    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    job.waitForCompletion(true);
}

public static final class PrimesMap extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, NullWritable, Text> {

    final NullWritable nw = NullWritable.get();
    private Text str=new Text();

    public final void map(final LongWritable key, final Text value, final Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        final int number = Integer.parseInt(value.toString());
        BigInteger num=new BigInteger("1");
        num=num.probablePrime(number,new SecureRandom());            
        str.set(num.toString());
        context.write(nw, str);

    }
  }    
 }
```

Comment: You only need one `new SecureRandom()` that you can reuse each time `PrimesMap.map()` is called.  You are wasting time by initialising a new instance every time.  If you are worried about security, then just add some new seed material every 10,000 calls.

Comment: rossum Thanks for replying.This will save  time.